# Select only values that match the conditions

Tags: mysql, business-intelligence

I have the following (example) table:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Customer | Subscription | Status     | Start Date | End Date   |
+----------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
|       1  | 1a001        | Pending    | 02.02.2020 |            |
|       1  | 1b002        | Pending    | 02.02.2020 | 05.02.2020 |
|       1  | 1c003        | Rejected   | 02.02.2020 |            |
|       1  | 1d004        | Incomplete | 02.02.2020 |            |
|       1  | 1e005        | Pending    | 07.02.2020 |            |
|       1  | 1f006        | Active     | 07.02.2020 |            |
|       2  | 2a001        | Pending    | 02.02.2020 |            |
|       2  | 2b002        | Pending    | 02.02.2020 |            |
|       2  | 3c003        | Rejected   | 02.02.2020 |            |
|       2  | 4d004        | Incomplete | 02.02.2020 |            |
|       2  | 5e005        | Pending    | 07.02.2020 | 07.02.2020 |
|       2  | 6f006        | Active     | 07.02.2020 |            |
+----------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

The aim is to select only Active Customers. Assumptions and conditions are:

1. One Customer_no can have many Subscriptions.
2. Active Customer = Customer that has at least one Active Subscription.
3. Active Subscription is when: Status = Active, the start_date is >= sysdate() and there is no end_date.

I am going to have very long list of Statuses what can be mapped using CASE statement. Is there any idea how to select distinct Active customers basing on that example? I am a begginer and do not know how to start with this task.

Thanks, Pawel

Comment: Go through the basic articles on [mysql tutorials](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/) and you will be able solve this by yourself and learn more.

Comment: Can you provide your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition for an active customer can be written like this:

```
status = 'Active' and start_date >= curdate() and end_date is null
```

So `group by customer` and use the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select customer
from tablename
group by customer
having sum(status = 'Active' and start_date >= curdate() and end_date is null)
```

If the `sum()` returns `0` then it is evaluated to `false`.
In any other case it is evaluated to `true`.

Comment: Hi, I think it will work for me. Thanks a lot, Pawel